# Communication between two components does not work and Sidebar is not updated

Tags: angular, input, binding, components, eventemitter

I want the content of the sidebar to change by clicking on the links Month and Year in the header. Unfortunately it doesn't work, there is no communication between the links and the components in the sidebar.

I have created a service where I have defined events, I have included this in the header and sidebar. Additionally I work with @Input.

### navigation.service.ts

```
public month: number;
public year: number;
public eventEmitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
sendEventUpdate(eventType: string) {
    this.eventEmitter.emit(eventType);
  }
```

### header.component.html

```
<a class="menu-link" (click)="clickMonth()">Monat</a>
<a (click)="clickYear()" class="menu-link" >Jahr</a>
```

### header.component.ts

```
private subscription: any;
private mSubscription: any;
public currentYear: number;
public currentMonth: number;
public select_month: string;
public select_year: string;

if (this.navService.eventEmitter) {
     this.subscription = this.navService.eventEmitter.subscribe(data => this.receiveEventData(data))
   }
   if (this.navService.monthEventEmitter) {
     this.mSubscription = this.navService.monthEventEmitter.subscribe(data => this.receiveMonthEventData(data));
   }

receiveEventData(eventType: string) {
   if (eventType === 'month') {
     this.currentMonth = this.navService.month;
     this.select_month = 'select month';
   } else if (eventType === 'year') {
     this.currentYear = this.navService.year;
     this.select_year = 'select year';
   }
  }

clickMonth() {
   if (this.select_month === null) {
     this.select_month = 'select month';
     this.select_year = null;
   } else {
     this.select_year = null;
   }
  }

  clickYear() {
    this.select_year = 'select year';
    this.select_month = null;
  }
```

### sidebar.component.html

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <!-- Nav month -->
  <app-sidebar-month-sub [month]="currentMonth" *ngIf="nav_month"></app-sidebar-month-sub>
  <!-- Nav year -->
  <app-sidebar-year-sub [year]="currentYear" *ngIf="nav_year"></app-sidebar-year-sub>
</div>
```

### sidebar.component.ts

```
  private subscription: any;
  public currentYear: number;
  public currentMonth: number;

  public nav_month: string;
  public nav_year: string;

    if (this.navService.eventEmitter) {
      this.subscription = this.navService.eventEmitter.subscribe((data) => this.receiveEventData(data));
    }

receiveEventData(eventType: string) {
  if (eventType === 'month') {
      this.currentMonth = this.navService.month;
      this.currentYear = null;
      this.reloadNavigation('month');
      this.nav_month = 'nav month';
      this.nav_year = null;
    } else if (eventType === 'year') {
      this.currentYear = this.navService.year;
      this.currentMonth = null;
      this.reloadNavigation('year');
      this.nav_year = 'nav year';
      this.nav_month = null;
    }
  }
```

### sidebar-month-sub.component.ts

```
 @Input() public month: number;
```

### sidebar-year-sub.component.html

```
 @Input() public year: number;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here header and sidebar are separate components.But i hope both have same parent component.If so you can create and `@output` event emitter in header component ,which emits value on clicking links.the value reaches on parent component and you can input that values to sidebar component using `@input` variable in sidebar and you can handle actions in `ngOnchanges` of sidebar component.

Header-component

```
@Output() buttonClick = new EventEmitter<{}>();

clickMonth() {
     this.buttonClick.emit(event);
}
```

And where you are using header component template

```
<header-component-name (buttonClick)="monthClicked($event)">
```

in code

```
public isclicked

monthClicked(e) {
   this.isclicked=e;
}
```

and these isclicked should pass to sidebar-component as input

```
<sidebar-component [monthclick]="isclicked" >
```

in code

```
@Input monthclick

ngOnChanges()
{
// you can get header menu clicks here.
}
```

Comment: please example :)

Comment: do you have same parent for header & sidebar?

Comment: Thank you for your answer from back then. I had dealt with it and followed your example. I built it up with events (with the help of the EventEmitters). In retrospect, this turns out to be very efficient.